ObservableObject Fatal error with StateObject called in app file
I am trying to add an EnvironmentObject var dataManager: ExerciseManager to my workout view. I keep getting "Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type ExerciseManager found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ExerciseManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view."
Here is the TodaysWorkoutView
import SwiftUI

struct TodaysWorkoutView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var dataManager: ExerciseManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(dataManager.movements, id: \.id) { exercise in
                HStack{
                    Text(exercise.ExerciseName)
                    Text(exercise.Sets)
                    Text(exercise.Reps)
                    Text(exercise.Rest)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
#Preview {
    NavigationStack{
        TodaysWorkoutView()
            .environmentObject(ExerciseManager())
    }
    
}

Here is my GetFit App file
import Firebase

@main
struct GetFit: App {
    @StateObject var dataManager = ExerciseManager()
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    @StateObject var data = TimerData()
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scene
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
                .environmentObject(data)
                .environmentObject(dataManager)
        }
        
        // TIMER CODE
        .onChange(of: scene) {
            (newScene, oldScene) in
            if newScene == .background{
                //Store the time
                data.leftTime = Date()
            }
            
            if newScene == .active && data.time != 0{
                //when entering back in this checks the difference in time and updates the counter
                let diff = Date().timeIntervalSince(data.leftTime)
                
                let currentTime = data.selectedTime - Int(diff)
                if currentTime >= 0{
                    withAnimation(.default) {
                        data.selectedTime = currentTime
                    }
                }
                else {
                    data.selectedTime = 0
                    data.time = 0
                    data.timerHeightChange = 0
                    data.timerViewOffset = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
                    data.buttonAnimation = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Movement File
import SwiftUI

struct Movement: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var ExerciseName: String
    var Sets: Int
    var Reps: Int
    var Rest: Int
    
}

ExerciseManager File
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

class ExerciseManager: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var movements: [Movement] = []
    
    init() {
        fetchExercises()
    }
    
    func fetchExercises() {
        movements.removeAll()
        let db  = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref = db.collection("MyMovement")
        ref.getDocuments{ snapshot, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                    let data = document.data()
                    
                    let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                    let ExerciseName = data["ExerciseName"] as? String ?? ""
                    let Sets = data["Sets"] as? Int ?? 3
                    let Reps = data["Reps"] as? Int ?? 10
                    let Rest = data["Rest"] as? Int ?? 45
                    
                    let exercise = Movement(id: id, ExerciseName: ExerciseName, Sets: Sets, Reps: Reps, Rest: Rest)
                    self.movements.append(exercise)
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

Content View File
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    
    var body: some View {
     
        Group {
            
            if viewModel.userSession != nil {
                //THIS IS WHERE YOU CHANGE WHAT PAGE POPS UP ON START UP IF LOGGED IN
                TabView {
                    ExercisesView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("Exercises")
                            Image(systemName: "figure.run")
                        }
                    ProfileView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("Profile")
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                        }
                    TodaysWorkoutView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("Plan A Workout")
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                    ClockViewHome()
                        .tabItem {
                            Text("StopWatch")
                            Image(systemName: "clock")
                        }
                }
                .accentColor(.red)
                
            } else{
                LoginView()
            }
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

Can anyone help me figure out whats wrong with this?

show the code where you call your TodaysWorkoutView. Is it in a .sheet for example? Assuming you have declared your models as class ...: ObservableObject

I think you've got too many environmentObjects usually there is just one to load and save the model structs but if you're using Firebase usually you wouldn't even need that.

I can show the rest of the code here
